# Interpolating bathymetric points

Tags: raster, interpolation

How can I make a raster surface out of bathymetric points that are not equally spaced? The points are from a USGS hydrographic survey of a section of the Ohio River. I need to make a depth profile map for a school project. I have attached an example of the bathymetric points.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use interpolation methods such as kriging or IDW (there are more methods, but these are most likely to produce a better model. But you can make several tests). These methods also make a geostatistical evaluation to confirm the model.

See the following documentation to help you:

- ArcGIS: 
  http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0704/files/interpolating.pdf
- QGIS:
  https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html